# How do I get a vertical tab to copy paste?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I'm consuming a SOAP service that return some data back to me. Because it's an XML, whenever it tries to return some data tha contains a vertical tab (\0xb) it fails to parse the response because it's contains an invalid XML character.

This is happening in the client side and I need to reproduce that on my end. The only problem is that I can't find out how to have this \0xb character to input that on the system so I can call the SOAP service and have this happening on my end.

Is there any way to copy a vertical tab or anything I can do to reproduce this specific invalid character?

Answer (score 3):

The vertical tab character (here:  although it doesn't seem to print) is 0xb. I took a [hex to ascii converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html) and popped in `0b` and it gave me a copyable representation of the VT character.